# How to open a specific activity based on Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am currently working on a reminders app in which the user gets a notification with the name of the reminder and is then redirected to an activity which contains the text of the reminder in detail. 
I am however, only able to redirect to the same activity each time. 
I am using this code :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
```

So this redirects to the MainActivity on clicking the notification. I would like to redirect to a separate screen and then based on a key value display a text on that activity.
How do I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `PendingIntent` using another `Activity` and/or append extra information on the `Intent` you are using to create the `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class)
launchIntent.putExtra("myKey", "myValue");
//....
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, launchIntent , 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
```

And than, in you `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
//...
getIntent().getStringExtra("myKey")
//do your stuff..
```

Comment: No my question was as to how I can decide what will be displayed in 'AnotherActivity' based on which a certain value that I pass with the notification ?

Comment: @ShivamBhalla I've answered in the brackets also about that. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: But the app is only opening Main Launcher activity only!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value in the intent . eg.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
contentIntent.putExtra("phone", value);
contentIntent.putExtra("name", value);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, contentIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question has already been anwered and accepted, but here's another method:

```
int mId = 1;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setNumber(1);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(mId, builder.build());
```