# Android google play games select activity to launch when clicked on notification

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is there a way to select which activity to launch when you press on a game services notification? It always brings me to the main activity, even though I have registered my NotificationListener in another activity. Is there a intent extra/bundle I have to look for? Or something else?

EDIT: Through another question thread here on StackOverflow I found out every intent launched by a google play games notification contains the flag `0x14000000`.
Is it ok to just check for this flag and redirect the user to the actual multiplayer activity?

Comment: If it's for an activity in your own app, it should be possible. The answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695788/how-to-open-a-specific-activity-based-on-notification) might help.

Comment: @qwertz Have you had any side effects from doing this? or did you use a different approach? i can't believe there isn't a way to get more information about what game/match the notification is is reference to.